# Probability Hitting a Target

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Problem:

- Jeff hits a target independently of Bob with probability $0.7$.
- Bob hits a target independently of Jeff with probability $0.4$.

Say they both shoot at a target at the same time.

What is the probability that the target is hit?

What is the probability that Jeff hit the target given that the target was hit?

My attempt:
For the target to be hit we have three possibilities. Either they both hit the target, only jeff hits the target or only bob hits the target so we get

$$(.4)(.7)+(0.3)(0.4)+(0.7)(0.6) =.82$$

To find the probability that Jeff hit the target given that the target was hit, would it be $$\frac{(.4)(.7)+(0.7)(0.6)}{.82}=\frac{.7}{.82}=\frac{70}{82} .$$

Does this work?
Thanks

Comment: Leaving an answer as $\frac {.4}{.82}$ is bad form.  But otherwise the calculation looks good.

Comment: thanks, we werent allowed calculators.

Comment: Sure, but even so.  $\frac {.4}{.82}=\frac {40}{82}=\frac {20}{41}$ can be done without calculators.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Your calculation is for Bob, not Jeff.  The $.3\times .4$ term is incorrect.

Comment: why is that term wrong? the .3 times .4 is when jeff does not hit, but bob does

Comment: Yes but you want the probability that Jeff hits it, not Bob.

Answer (score 1):

I believe for your second answer should be $\frac{(.4)(.7)+(0.7)(0.6)}{0.82}$

$$P(J|T)=\frac{P(T|J)P(J)}{P(T)}$$

$P(T|J)$ is 1. $P(J)$ is $(.4)(.7)+(0.7)(0.6)$ and you calculated $P(T)$ correctly in the first part

Comment: wouldnt that be when they both hit the target plus when bob hits the target on top? why dont we look at where jeff hits the target?

Comment: @elcharlosmaster you said Jeff is the one who hits the target with probability $0.7$, right? Bob is the one who hits with probability $0.4$.

Comment: The top should be P{both hit the target} +P(jeff hits, bob misses}